# How to call my index.php without file name

Tags: php, web-services

I have created a file `api/v1/index.php` in my website root folder and in this file I have created webservice.

When I am calling API using url `api/v1/index.php/myfunction` then it's return me result. Here `api/v1/index.php` is file path and `myfunction` is function name.

But I want to call this API using url `api/v1/myfunction`. but it is not give me result (I know this url search for `index.php` in `myfunction` folder)

How to skip `index.php` from my url or Is there any another method to call API url without mention file name.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `.htaccess` file in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

`mod_rewrite` needs to be enabled on the server

Comment: Where will give `api/v1/index.php` path in rewriteRule?

Comment: Hello @eskimo, please update your answer, How to add rewriteRule for my path `api/v1/index.php`?